# Walmart API Token VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, post, walmart-api

I am trying to connect my Access db To Wallmart's API and i get this error..
`{"error":[{"code":"SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_GATEWAY_API","info":"System encountered some internal error.","severity":"ERROR","category":"DATA","causes":[],"errorIdentifiers":{}}]}`

this is my code:

```
 Dim s As String
  
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 
 Me.Refresh
 
WalmartAPIUserKey =...
WalmartSecretKey=....
encodeData = Base64Encode(WalmartAPIUserKey & ":" & WalmartSecretKey)

xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token", False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & encodeData
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "WM_SVC.NAME", "Walmart Marketplace"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID", "123456789c"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.Type", "........"


s = "grant_type=client_credentials"
xmlhttp.send s

MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
Debug.Print (xmlhttp.responseText)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: The error message indicates that It's a problem at their end, not yours. Give them a few hours or a few days to fix their stuff.

Comment: @Dai Walmart actually has some of the worst validation in their endpoints, usually an internal server error just means that your payload is being send wrong in their API. They have awful validation and error handling.